# htaccess RewriteBase

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have two directories in my root: `/dev` and `/live`.

All content inside these directories have relative paths such as `/css/style.css` or `/js/home.js`.

I want to be able change the root directory using htaccess so that the relative paths would become `/live/css/style.css` etc or `/dev/css/style.css` depending on which version of the site I was using.

I have tried using the following code in .htaccess located inside the `/live` directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /live/
```

I have also tried using `RewriteBase /public_html/live/`.

But, the content paths are still `http://domain.com/css/style.css` rather than `http://domain.com/live/css/style.css` when I view the site.

Has anyone any ideas?

Thank you.

EDIT>>
Sorry I should explain that my root htaccess has the following rules pointing towards the two directories:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.us$ /live/index.php?tag=%3 [L,P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^((www\.)?([a-z]+)\.)domain\.us$ /live/index.php?tag=%3 [L,P]
```

Comment: This is to switch between a production and development site, correct? Is the example `http://domain.com/live/css/style.css` just explanatory, or do you wish the external URLs to reflect which site is active? If the latter, why?

Comment: Yeah, to be able to switch between the two and keep the relative file paths.

Comment: A path that begins with "/" is absolute, not relative. What is the problem with using a rewrite rule?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[`RewriteBase`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase) lets you fix issues with how URLs get translated to file paths and back again. It's not for what you're using it for. Use a standard `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/live
RewriteRule ^(/?)(.*) /live/$2
```

Comment: Thanks you for the reply. Can I use RewriteBase to change the relative file paths such as /css/style.css to /live/css/style.css?

Comment: As I already said, it's not for what you want it for. `RewriteBase` is for mapping between URL paths and file paths in specific stages of Apache request processing. Read the documentation (which is linked to above).