# .htaccess mod_rewrite not working correctly

Tags: apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, wamp

I'm using Wamp on my dev machine to develop a project. This is my .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 [L] 
RewriteBase /project/
```

This is put in localhost/project, so that any requests like localhost/project/something , are routed to localhost/project/index.php/something

However, they are being routed to localhost/index.php/something

I suspect it has something to do with how I'm using RewriteBase. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

You need to remove the leading slash in your rule:

```
# no slash---------v
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
```

Apache kind of guesses whether the targets of a `RewriteRule` is a URL-path or a file-path. When it starts with a slash, it assumes it's a URL-path and that it's absolute, so it'll go to the document root's index.php. Without the slash, it'll either guess a file-path or use the rewrite base to help determine which to use.

You should also move the `RewriteBase` directive above your rule.

Answer (score 1):

Why not put the base in the rewriterule?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /project/index.php?$1 [L]
```

Edit:

This question might help you: [htaccess RewriteBase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844069/htaccess-rewritebase)